# Not my files in git status after conflict resolution

Tags: git

I did `git pull` and Git shows me:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>   ..files list...
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

OK, I added files in Git, committed my changes and then I did `git pull` again, Git shows:

> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result

So I fixed the problematic files and I did `git status`. But there are many files in the list that I didn't change. They seem like files that I got by pulling. Is it normal or do I have to do something before I commit?

Comment: Usually it should not be conflict in those files, what type of changes it is? Are you sure that 1. you are pulling from right repository? 2. you did not change those files (using e.g. code reformat)?

Comment: Could you show your flow in a bit more detail. Command by command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a normal behaviour.

What you see is the full list of **all** the files in the merge, even if you have added only a single file.

Nothing to worry about, simply push your changes.

Read more about it here:
http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-conflict-conflicts-and-resolutions/

---

When git merge, all files that can be automatically merged are automatically merged and staged. Files which could not be automatically merged are updated in your working area with conflict markers and you have to fix them.

This is why you see a lot of files.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated, this is the expected behavior. The reason why it behaves like this is because of the way Git stores commits.

Commits in Git know about every single file in your *tree*, not only the ones it modified/added. However, for optimization reasons, the files are not duplicated. Instead, Git commits **point** to files, which are stored in the *files database*.

The files are stored in the database according to their contents, so that files with the exact same contents will be reused. In practice, that means that if you commit a file to a repository and never change it again, all commits will be pointing to that **same entry** in the files database.

Say you have the following commit history:

```
* d787d (master) Change line #2 of A.txt
| * c565c (feature/something) Change line #1 of A.txt
|/
* b343b Add file B.txt
* a121a Add file A.txt
```

In this scenario:

- `a121a` points to entry `A1` in the files database
- `b343b` points to entries `A1` and `B1`
- `c565c` points to entries `A2`* and `B1`
- `d787d` points to entries `A3`* and `B1`

*Because the contents of `A.txt` have changed, Git has to create a new entry in the files database

When you ask to merge the branch `feature/something` into `master`, Git will see it needs to somehow combine `A2` and `A3` into a new entry `A4` (if it can't do this automatically, it will ask you to fix the conflicts manually), so the commit history will be:

```
* e909e (master) Merge branch 'feature/something'
|\
| * c565c (feature/something) Change line #1 of A.txt
* | d787d Change line #2 of A.txt
|/
* b343b Add file B.txt
* a121a Add file A.txt
```

And `e909e` will point to entries `A4` and `B1`.

That being said, the files you are seeing in the `git status` are all the files that had to be combined by Git (or by you) in order to merge the two branches together.

Bear in mind that this is a simplified model of how things actually work in Git. If you are interested in learning more, read about the [internals](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) of Git.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pull the new code sometimes the conflicts occur because of changes in code of both the branches.

The situation you are facing is normal.

Simply, add the files in which you fixed the conflicts and commit them.

Answer (score 0):

The changes you see are not only your files, but also all the files that you are merging in. **Make sure to include all of those files in your merge commit**. If you don't, you will undo other people's changes.